# Attribute 'getvalue' Error in Python (Pandas)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, read.csv

I try to read .csv file using Pandas. When my programme starts to read a file it will get an error attribute not found.
Output

[image: **This is my error**]

here is my code.

```
in line 23: __location = r'/Users/A/Documents/Co/1/Information/CSV/image_tags.csv'
in line 25: __image_tags= DataFrame()
...
line 35:    self.__image_tags=pd.read_csv(self.__location)
...
line 73:    name_row=self.__image_tags.columns.get_values().tolist()
```

Does anyone know how to solve?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `self.__image_tags.columns.get_values().tolist()`? Maybe it's a logical problem and we can help you.

Comment: Once my programme starts to run then I have to write a keyword for example appletree. Then my programme will look at the csv file and print the image name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is most likely that you are asking pandas to read an empty file/ non-existent file. I face that problem in Open-CV too when I type in the wrong file name. Check your file name.

The logic works like this:
`variable = Non-Existant file` - so variable = NonType Object ie.Nothing
so something to the variable
eg: `variable +=1` - ie. Nothing = Nothing +1
Output: `Error`

Comment: my file exists and the data is available.

Comment: Is there any problem with my location?

Comment: @Unknown try adding the line: `print(type(variable))` If it comes out as Nonetype, something is wrong with your import. If not, it is something else.

Comment: I try to add ```print(type(variable))``` but I got same error

Comment: @Unknown of course. I am asking for the output of that line so we can see what is wrong. Is it Nonetype as expected? Can't wait to see whether I guessed this right or not :)

Comment: I add this ```print(type(variable))``` after line 73. but it will not print any value. If I change that location and I will get error ```variable``` not found.

Comment: I got this type of error if I put before 73 line ```print(type(__image_tags))
NameError: name '_Basic__image_tags' is not defined``` for the ```variable``` it say not find

Comment: @Unknown so you didn't import anything. try printing different stuff to confirm this. Anyways, something is wrong with data importing/ variable defining. When you put var = the value / for example, var = 1 or var = function(1), check whether something is in the spot of '1'

Comment: I try with this one ```print(type(1))``` and I got <class 'int'> erorr.

Comment: @Unknown sorry. By '1', its just another variable. Should have used x. Sorry for the confusion. Anyways, something is wrong with the importing of your data. It is probably line 23. Trying printing the content of line 23, ie: print(location). Tell me what comes out

Comment: I try to print ```location``` and it will print file location.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, I think this will solve your problem:

```py
__location = r'/Users/A/Documents/Co/1/Information/CSV/image_tags.csv'
__image_tags= DataFrame()

self.__image_tags=pd.read_csv(self.__location)

appletree_keyword = "keyword"

image_name = self.image_tags.loc[self.image_tags['tree_names_column'] == appletree_keyword]['image_name_column'].values[0]
```

*tree_names_column* is the column that contains appletree names. *image_name_column* is the column that you are searching for image names.

P.S.: These variable names are confusing though. Check out [PEP8 recommendations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) and [this](https://hackernoon.com/understanding-the-underscore-of-python-309d1a029edc).

Comment: I try with your code you already define appletree_keyword. in my case, the user will write ```appletree``` at run time and then I will get the output.

Comment: I try to get output at run time but I got an error in ```'tree_names_column```. ```KeyError: 'tree_names_column'```

Comment: Yea I think you can alter my code to get the name from user. Also `tree_names_column` was just a placeholder for my example. I don't know what the exact column names are in your dataframe.

Comment: ```name_row=self.__image_tags.loc[self.__image_tags['tree_names_column'] == __primitive_input]['image_name_column'].values[0]``` I try this. ```__primitive_input``` i am collecting keyword from the user in run time